# How to make a button round in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button

How can you make a button round like this using jquery mobile?

(*By the way, I am not asking about the glare effect in the sample image*)

[image: round button]

Comment: read this: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: And have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: you both could have pointed me in the direction of border-radius ... -1 to both of you

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Why didn't you tag it CSS? you make it sound like you want a JQuery mobile solution but instead you wanted CSS? Please be more clear next time.

Comment: Gung Foo ... I have spent 60 hours per week for the last 12 years in front of my computer developing things and things and things  ... asking what I have tried is like me asking you how many times you have picked your toenails ...

Comment: @zenith ... not correct ... I did not know what I needed .. css happens to be the solution that works ... as far as I knew I was going to need some relentless jquery DOM manipulator (which is what I was expecting) ... thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/XMu9t/

```
#custom-btn {
    width: 100px !important;
    height: 100px !important;
    border-radius: 50% !important;
    http://www.lawyersgunsmoneyblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/american-flag-2a.jpg
}

#custom-btn span span {
    height: 100px !important;  
    line-height: 70px;
}
```

## More info

If you want to learn how to do this kind of changes by yourself you should check this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**, it will teach you how to do this by yourself.

Comment: I would mention that Seidr's usage of 50% is a quick catch all to ensure circle ...

Comment: also, in my case I did not want text on the button, and when I deleted the inner text, things went bad. So I added a &nbsp;, and it worked just like your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You could use a border-radius of 50% on a DIV element, paired with a background-image of the flag. You could then bind a click event to this DIV element in order to use it to perform actions.

```
.circle_button {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:url(flag.png) center center no-repeat;
}

jQuery(".circle_button").click(function(){
    //add click code here
});

<div class="circle_button"></div>
```

Reference: http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles

Perhaps this can be accomplished with jQuery Mobile using their button class, but looking at their documentation it just lets you specify whether or not the button has rounded corners, not specifically the border-radius of the button.

Comment: thanks ... +1 on the 50%, which seems to necessarily ensure a circle ... I did not choose this as the answer though, because I was wondering about the jqm issue, where it wraps new elements around existing.